# Yeoman Walkthrough angular js not working

Tags: angularjs

I am doing the to do list app but having difficulties my code for my main.html is

```
< body>
<div class="jumbotron">
<h2>My todos</h2>
<p class="form-group" ng-repeat="todo in todos">
<input type="text" ng-model="todo" class="form-control">
</p>
</div>
</body>
```

and my code for main.js is

```
use strict';


angular.module('mytodoApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.todos = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];
});
```

can anyone shed some light please?

Comment: You forgot to include your app inside html https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp and then use ng-controller to match your controller. Please provide walkthrough URL or something, so we can check that too.

Comment: Also - what are your results / errors given? Which step are you at?

Comment: doh so i did should i put <body ng-app = "mytodoApp">?

Comment: When you check your generated index.html, does it have <body ng-app="mytodoApp"> inside?

Comment: your right you Isorted it thnkyou very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I go through your HTML briefly, one thing I notice is that you are missing an include of your app inside HTML using ng-app directive. Then also ng-controller of course.

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

An example:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="personController">
```

**EDIT:** Probably you are doing this http://yeoman.io/codelab/setup.html ?
I see, Yeoman should create what I mentioned for you and it probably doesn't.

If I were you, I would check the generated files and see if they match. 
http://yeoman.io/codelab.html#source-files and provide the ng-app and controller properly? If you are indeed working on the mentioned tutorial, does [index file](https://github.com/addyosmani/yeoman-examples/blob/master/angular-localStorage-todos/app/index.html) match?